# How can I write a LPeg pattern that never matches anything?

Tags: lua, lpeg

Is there a way to create an LPeg pattern that always fails to match anything? I'm not talking about matching the empty string, I'm talking about a pattern that always fails so if you put it in an ordered choice it always will fall back to the second option.

The reason for this is that I am writing a small parser with LPEG and I wish I could write

```
 operators = empty_pattern + "==" + "~=" + "<=" + ">=" + "<" + ">"
```

instead of

```
 operators = lpeg.P("==") + "~=" + "<=" + ">=" + "<" + ">"
```

Comment: On lpeg.re you can also try `(&. !.)`, which means there is a next char and there is no next char, which is always false since these two scenarios are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`lpeg.P( false )`](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg/#op-p) is the simplest way.

> If the argument is a boolean, the result is a pattern that always succeeds or always fails (according to the boolean value), without consuming any input.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed.